# Unable to change back end acl permissions to civicrm?

Tags: joomla, permissions, acl

I am trying to add CiviCRM to a joomla cms group named CRM Admin.  When I try to modify the acl for this group in the cms global configurations, it will not save the changes.  I can assign permissions to all other components except CiviCRM.  My intent is to allow the CRM Admin access to the Administration Login but only have access to CiviCRM component.  The only way I can do this is if I add the Super User ACL permission to this group.  I don't want to do this.  How can I get around it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue running Joomla 3.5.1 and CiviCRM 4.7.5. CiviCRM changes to the ACL will not save even with max_input_vars set and verified to be set at 14500.

Comment: I am having the same issue and have not found a work-around. I know I can go into the database somehow and manually change variables but this did not end well when I attempted it. It seems the page is too long and no matter what I change the max_input_vars to, I have the same result.